# Context Menu (RightClickMenu) Excel: Works only in one book, I want it to work everywhere

Tags: excel, vba

I have books with `"ContextMenu" code (XML + VBA)`. Everything works fine but not all the books. There are 2 variants of the code. 1 - starts with the Excel book; 2 - works after clicking on the button in "ContextMenu".

I used the methods described on these sites (both sites have same information).
[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg469862(v=office.14)#adding-controls-to-the-cell-context-menu-by-using-ribbon-extensibility)
[rondebruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win014.htm)

I modernized codes a bit.
Below publish code for one Excel book with "Dynamic menu".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
         <dynamicMenu 
            id="MyDynamicMenu" 
            label= "My Dynamic Menu" 
            imageMso="HappyFace" 
            getContent="GetContent" 
            insertBeforeMso="Cut"/>
      </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

---

```
Option Explicit

'MyDynamicMenu (component: dynamicMenu, attribute: getContent), 2010+
Sub GetContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Dim xml As String

        xml = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
              "<button id=""but1"" imageMso=""Help"" label=""About"" onAction=""HelpMacro""/>" & _
              "<button id=""but2"" imageMso=""FindDialog"" label=""Find information"" onAction=""FindMacro""/>" & _
              "<menu id=""MyMacroSubMenu"" label=""Macro Sub-Menu"" itemSize=""large"">" & _
              "<button id=""Sub1But1"" imageMso=""AppointmentColor1"" label=""Macro1"" onAction=""Macro1"" description=""Description Macro1""/>" & _
              "<button id=""Sub1But2"" imageMso=""AppointmentColor2"" label=""Macro3"" onAction=""Macro2"" description=""Description Macro2""/>" & _
              "<button id=""Sub1But3"" imageMso=""AppointmentColor3"" label=""Macro3"" onAction=""Macro3"" description=""Description Macro3""/>" & _
              "</menu>" & _
              "</menu>"

    returnedVal = xml
End Sub

'Callback for macro
Sub FindMacro(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Find macro"
End Sub

Sub Macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Macro 1 in menu"
End Sub

Sub Macro2(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Macro 2 in menu"
End Sub

Sub Macro3(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Macro 3 in menu"
End Sub
```

=============================================

1. I tried to add through - Developer > Add-ins
2. Putting the code in - C:\Users[MyPC]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB
3. Also when I put this code, I get an error:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

 Call AddToCellMenu End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

 Call DeleteFromCellMenu End Sub
```

NOTHING HELPS!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this...when you right click there will be a side menu for `upper case, lower case, proper case`.

```
Sub AddToCellMenu()

    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl

    ' Delete the controls first to avoid duplicates.
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Add one built-in button(Save = 3) to the Cell context menu.
    ContextMenu.Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3, before:=1

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu.
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=2)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "ToggleCaseMacro"
        .FaceId = 59
        .Caption = "Toggle Case Upper/Lower/Proper"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

    ' Add a custom submenu with three buttons.
    Set MySubMenu = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=3)

    With MySubMenu
        .Caption = "Case Menu"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "UpperMacro"
            .FaceId = 100
            .Caption = "Upper Case"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "LowerMacro"
            .FaceId = 91
            .Caption = "Lower Case"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "ProperMacro"
            .FaceId = 95
            .Caption = "Proper Case"
        End With
    End With

    ' Add a separator to the Cell context menu.
    ContextMenu.Controls(4).BeginGroup = True
End Sub

Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Delete the custom controls with the Tag : My_Cell_Control_Tag.
    For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl

    ' Delete the custom built-in Save button.
    On Error Resume Next
    ContextMenu.FindControl(ID:=3).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub ToggleCaseMacro()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedRange = Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If selectedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
        Select Case cell.value
        Case UCase(cell.value): cell.value = LCase(cell.value)
        Case LCase(cell.value): cell.value = StrConv(cell.value, vbProperCase)
        Case Else: cell.value = UCase(cell.value)
        End Select
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub UpperMacro()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedRange = Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If selectedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
        cell.value = UCase(cell.value)
    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub LowerMacro()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedRange = Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If selectedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
        cell.value = LCase(cell.value)
    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ProperMacro()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedRange = Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If selectedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
        cell.value = StrConv(cell.value, vbProperCase)
    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I olso have this code. How can i insert in "Dynamic Menu" my own icon in this VBA?

Comment: @rediffusion is this not what you wanted? It creates the side menu for you...all you need to do is tweek a few things here and there to suit your needs. You can change the `faceid` to something different... To you your own img i don't know to be honest never tried.

Comment: 0K i got you! i will use this one.
But if someone has interesting code please feel free to share with community :)

Answer (score 0):

### I figured out why it didn't work.

---

1. Open New Workbook then "Save As" "RightClickMenu.xlam"
2. Then put it here `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\`
3. Above on the proposed site, 2 variants of "*RightClickMenu*". I decided to use without dynamicMenu, because it works faster.
4. Open our book already in [Ribbon XML Editor](http://novikov.gq/products/ribbonxmleditor/ribbonxmleditor.html) ↵ or [Custom UI Editor](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1224211-download-custom-ui-editor.html) ↵ and paste the XML-code there:

↴

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
         <menu
    id="SubMenu1"
    label="RightClickMenu"
    insertBeforeMso="QuickAnalysis"
    imageMso="AcceptAndAdvance">
            <button idMso="Calculator"/>
            <button idMso="MultiplicationSign"/>
   <menuSeparator id="sep_1"/>
   <menu
      id="SubMenu2"
      image="Hand"
      label="Спец Примечание"
      itemSize="large">
      <button
      id="MenuButton1"
      label="Yellow"
               imageMso="ColorYellow"
      onAction="Special_NoteYellow"/>
      <button
      id="MenuButton2"
      label="Teal"
               imageMso="ColorTeal"
      onAction="Special_NoteTeal"/>
      </menu>
         </menu>
        <menuSeparator id="sep_2" insertBeforeMso="Cut"/>
      </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

5. Next, insert VBA-code <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> - these are our buttons. You can add as many buttons as you want. The DynamicMenu can be expanded as you like:

↴

```js
Option Explicit

Sub Special_NoteYellow(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim myComm As Comment
  If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("The cell already contains a note, delete?", 4) - 7 Then
      ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

Set myComm = ActiveCell.AddComment
    With myComm.Shape 'exhibiting the required format
      .Height = 110
      .Width = 200
      .AutoShapeType = 1
      .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
      .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .DrawingObject.Font.Name = "Consolas"
      .DrawingObject.Font.FontStyle = "normal"
      .DrawingObject.Font.Size = 10
     End With
      'emulate the choice of "Change note"
       SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub

Sub Special_NoteTeal(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim myComm As Comment
  If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("The cell already contains a note, delete?", 4) - 7 Then
      ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

Set myComm = ActiveCell.AddComment
    With myComm.Shape 'exhibiting the required format
      .Height = 110
      .Width = 200
      .AutoShapeType = 1
      .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 15
      .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .DrawingObject.Font.Name = "Consolas"
      .DrawingObject.Font.FontStyle = "normal"
      .DrawingObject.Font.Size = 10
     End With
      'emulate the choice of "Change note"
       SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub
```

6. Attention! In order to save the changes you need:

   - add-In `.xlam` “Save as” `.xlsm`.
   - Edit what we need (insert icons, buttons, menus, etc.).
   - Next “Save as” `.xlam`!
7. Now let's talk about inserting your icon. For menu we can change icon in [Ribbon XML Editor](http://novikov.gq/products/ribbonxmleditor/ribbonxmleditor.html) ↵ or [Custom UI Editor](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1224211-download-custom-ui-editor.html) ↵. Use this entry - `imageMso="HappyFace"` or we can insert own icon `image="Hand"` for staticMenu. 
   If we use `DynamicMenu` code which is described above, the icon you need to insert `image="Hand"` line in the VBA.

> P.S. - also for own Menu we can use Attributes:

↴

```js
button
checkBox
control
dynamicMenu
gallery
menu
menuSeparator
splitButton
toggleButton
```

- If we need turn `RightClickMenu` for us in all books:
- Go to the developer tab > Excel add-Ins.
- Or... File > Options > add-Ins > Manage > Excel add-Ins > Go... (check the add-in that we created, if you put in another folder – use the “Browse” button).

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)[vba](/questions/tagged/vba)